# How does strtok work exactly?

Tags: c, eclipse, strtok

I have a file that i want to read from in c,
the file's format is as follows :

```
<city> <pokemon1> <pokemon2>; <near_city1> <near_city2>
```

for example: `paris pidgey pikachu; london berlin`
I want to be able to cut this row into tokens using strtok, but for some reason its not working properly.

My code: lets say I have this row read from the file using fgets and put into char* row.
so what I did was :

```
char* city_name = strtok(location_temp, " "); // to receive city
char* pokemons_names = strtok(strtok(location_temp, " "),";");
```

Although , this code brings segmentation fault later on, so I followed the debugger and noticed that the second code line is not being executed properly.

Help ?

Comment: Read the documentation about the function.

Comment: [This `strtok` reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strtok) might help?

Comment: What **specifically** about the documentation you should have read is not clear? What did you find by a simple serach did not help?

Comment: i read the documentation and I looked for the solution but haven't found one. what I cant figure out is does strtok change the original string? how can i reach the second word in the row seperated by spaces? any examples on this specific format please?

Comment: *does strtok change the original string?* Yes. It writes a string terminator `'\0'` at the start of each delimitation.

Comment: The MSVC [man page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2c8d19sb.aspx) has an example usage.

Answer (score 3):

These statements

```
char* city_name = strtok(location_temp, " "); // to receive city
char* pokemons_names = strtok(strtok(location_temp, " "), ";");
```

are valid and can not result in a segmentation fault provided that `location_temp` is not equal to `NULL` and does not point to a string literal.

However this code snippet does not do what you expect. The first and the second statements return the same pointer that is the address of the initial word in the string pointed to by `location_temp`.

You should write at least like

```
char* city_name = strtok(location_temp, " "); // to receive city
strtok(NULL, " ");
char* pokemons_names = strtok( NULL, ";");
```

I think that the segmentation fault occurs because you do not copy the resulted strings in separate character arrays. But without your actual code it is difficult to name the reason exactly.

You should read the description of the function `strtok` before using it.

Take into account that the original string is changed within the function by inserting the terminating zero for the extracted substring and the function keeps the address of the next part of the original string after the inserted terminating zero until it will be called with the first argument unequal to NULL..

Answer (score 1):

You can use `strtok()` like this to gather your information about each line:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void) {
    char string[] = "paris pidgey pikachu; london berlin";

    char *city = strtok(string, " ");
    printf("city: %s\n", city);

    char *pokemon_names = strtok(NULL, ";");
    printf("pokemon names: %s\n", pokemon_names);

    char *near_cities = strtok(NULL, "\n");
    memmove(near_cities, near_cities+1, strlen(near_cities)); /* removes space at start of string */
    printf("near cities: %s\n", near_cities);

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
city: paris
pokemon names: pidgey pikachu
near cities: london berlin
```

It really depends how your storing these strings though.